# AJAX - Extracting Info from JSON Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, api-design

I have data in a JSON object with the following format:

```
[{"Feature 1 Name":111,"Feature 2":111,"Feature 3":"stringforfeature3"}]
```

I've started to write some code to pull information from an API, but am not sure how to extract information (for instance, "stringforfeature3" if I somehow call "Feature 3") from the JSON object.

```
ajax: {
        type: "GET",
        url: '/api/apiname/info/moreinfo', //where i'm pulling info from
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
          return {
            title: // Where I'd like to use the extracted information
          };
        }
      },
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have a look at this [jQuery documention](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to extract the data using square bracket notation:

```
success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    return {
        title: data[0]['Feature 3']
      };
    }
```

You result is an array, so I used `data[0]` to get the first item of array, or `{"Feature 1 Name":111,"Feature 2":111,"Feature 3":"stringforfeature3"}`.

In JavaScript you can access the same variable either using `object.variable` or `object['variable']`. Since your variable name has spaces, you are left with second option - `data[0]['Feature 3']`. Your result will be `stringforfeature3`.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the response is an array, You need to get the first element like this

```
response = data[0];
```

Do you know each of the keys in advance? If yes,

```
{ title: response['Feature 3'] }
```

Else you can loop over response

```
for (var key in response) {
    if (p.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        console.log(key + " -> " + response[key]);
    }
}
```